# Finding the time to cover some distance

Tags: physics

[image]
My turn :
From the given information we get the position vector of the walker is $6i + 8j$
Now the party is  moving with horizontal speed $5 km h^{-1}$
Which means it velocity is $5i$ 
So it will not reach the walker , does the "horizontal" means some thing else ?

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to type out the image in your question. Many users cannot see images and they are also not searchable on the site so will mean that fewer people will answer your question

Comment: There are 3 directions: $\mathbf i, \mathbf j, \mathbf k$ - the directions of the positive $x, y, z$-axes, respectively. Normal convention is that $z$ is the vertical coordinate, so $\mathbf k$ is vertical, and $\mathbf i$ and $\mathbf j$ are both horizontal, as is the entire plane that they determine. You should assume that the rescuers are heading straight towards where they think the walker is at.